# Postgres positive, integer, non-null estimate for the number of distinct non-null values

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

I am asked to write a query that uses pg stats to return:

- the table name, as tablename;
- the attribute name, as attname;
- the number of distinct non-null values that Postgres estimates that this attribute has, as a distval attribute;
- and some histogram data.

However, this number distval should be positive integer, while my query outputs negative numbers (ex. -0.86514354). What am I doing wrong here?

The query is:

```
SELECT tablename,
       attname,
       n_distinct as distval,
       (histogram_bounds::text::varchar[])[1] as min,
       (histogram_bounds::text::varchar[])[array_upper(histogram_bounds::text::varchar[],1)] as max

FROM information_schema.columns,pg_stats 
WHERE tablename = table_name
  AND attname = column_name
  AND (NOT (information_schema.columns.table_schema LIKE 'pg_%'
            OR information_schema.columns.table_schema = 'information_schema'))
  AND (information_schema.columns.data_type ='character varying')
  AND (table_name NOT in (SELECT viewname FROM pg_views))
LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-stats.html) explains that:

> `n_distinct` `float4`
>
> If greater than zero, the estimated number of distinct values in the column. If less than zero, the negative of the number of distinct values divided by the number of rows. (The negated form is used when `ANALYZE` believes that the number of distinct values is likely to increase as the table grows; the positive form is used when the column seems to have a fixed number of possible values.) For example, -1 indicates a unique column in which the number of distinct values is the same as the number of rows.

So you can use a query like this:

```
SELECT s.schemaname,
       s.tablename,
       s.attname as columnname,
       CASE WHEN s.n_distinct >= 0
            THEN s.n_distinct
            ELSE - t.reltuples * s.n_distinct
       END AS distval
FROM pg_stats AS s
   JOIN pg_class AS t
      ON s.tablename = t.relname
         AND s.schemaname::regnamespace = t.relnamespace;
```